# Restrict route to controller namespace in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to restrict the controllers of my ASP.NET Core routes to a certain namespace.

In previous versions of ASP.NET MVC there was an overload that provided a `string[] namespaces` parameter when adding routes. This is missing in ASP.NET MVC 6. So after some googling, I tried playing around with something like

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    var dataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary {
        {
            "Namespaces", new[] {"ProjectA.SomeNamespace.Controllers"}
        }
    };

    routes.MapRoute(
         name: "default",
         template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
         defaults: null,
         constraints: null,
         dataTokens: dataTokens
    );
});
```

but it doesn't seem to do what I want. Is there a way to restrict the routing engine to a certain namespace?

**Update**

I just realized it may have to do something with the fact that I'm using attribute routing on each individual controller? Does attribute routing funk up the routes defined by `app.UseMvc()`?

**Update 2**

More details:

I've two completely independent Web API projects. Incidentally, a few of the routes are identical in both (ie. `~/api/ping`). These projects are independent in Production, one is an endpoint for users, one is an endpoint for administrators.

I also have unit tests, using `Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost`. A few of these unit tests require functionality of both of these Web API projects (ie. need "admin" endpoint to fully setup a test case for "user"). But when I reference both API projects, the TestHost gets confused because of the identical routes and it complains about "multiple matching routes":

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
    ProjectA.SomeNamespace.Controllers.PingController.Ping
    ProjectB.SomeNamespace.Controllers.PingController.Ping
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionSelector.SelectAsync(RouteContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.<RouteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
```

Comment: "multiple matching routes" - can you put full error with stack trace here?

Comment: Sure, please see my updated question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update:**

I've found solution through using ActionConstraint. You have to add custom Action Constraint attribute about duplicate actions.

Example with duplicate Index methods.

First HomeController

```
namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [NamespaceConstraint]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Second HomeController

```
namespace WebApplication
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [NamespaceConstraint]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Configure routing

```
app.UseMvc(cR =>
   cR.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}", null, null, 
   new { Namespace = "WebApplication.Controllers.HomeController" }));
```

Action constraint

```
namespace WebApplication
{
    public class NamespaceConstraint : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
        {
            var dataTokenNamespace = (string)routeContext.RouteData.DataTokens.FirstOrDefault(dt => dt.Key == "Namespace").Value;
            var actionNamespace = ((ControllerActionDescriptor)action).MethodInfo.DeclaringType.FullName;

            return dataTokenNamespace == actionNamespace;
        }
    }
}
```

**First answer:**

> Does attribute routing funk up the routes defined by app.UseMvc()?

Attribute routing and Convention-based routing (`routes.MapRoute(...`) work independently. And attribute routes have advantage over convention routes.

> but it doesn't seem to do what I want. Is there a way to restrict the routing engine to a certain namespace?

[Answer from developers](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/issues/217#issuecomment-146598807):

> Instead of using a list of namespaces to group your controllers we recommend using Areas. You can attribute your controllers (regardless of which assembly they are in) with a specific Area and then create a route for that Area.
>
> You can see a test website that shows an example of using Areas in MVC 6 here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/test/WebSites/RoutingWebSite.

**Example using Area with convention-based routing**

Controller:

```
//Reached through /admin/users
//have to be located into: project_root/Areas/Admin/
[Area("Admin")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{

}
```

Configure convention-based routing:

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
 {
         routes.MapRoute(
         "areaRoute",
         "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}",
         new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
 }
```

**Example using Area with attribute-based routing**

```
//Reached through /admin/users
//have to be located into: project_root/Areas/Admin/
[Area("Admin")]
[Route("[area]/[controller]/[action]", Name = "[area]_[controller]_[action]")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. This surely works in most cases, but I think it's sub-optimal in my special case (I should have provided more details, I will fix that immediately):

I've two completely independent Web API projects. Incidentally a few of the routes are identical (ie. `~/api/ping`). I have unit tests, using `Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost`. A few of these unit tests require functionality of both of these Web API projects (for example to fully setup a test case). But when I reference both API projects, the `TestHost` gets confused because of the identical routes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, using routing constraints here is a brilliant idea :) I'll mark your answer as the solution, you definitely deserve it, but will post another answer, too, because I had to slightly change your approach because the `dataTokens` won't work with attribute routing.

Comment: Thumbs up to Areas!

Comment: Great solution. I am using .NET Core 3.1 and I have found when debugging NamespaceConstraint.IsValidForRequest, routeContext.RouteData.DataTokens doesn't contain the namespace specified in endpoints.MapControllerRoute in Startup. Any ideas why it's absent?

Comment: @RyanPenfold Maybe routing system choosing different route without specified DataToken