# Restrict API route to controller namespace with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have found a similar question that relates to standard asp.net controllers, but i have tried it and it doesn't seem to be working with the apicontroller.

[Restrict route to controller namespace in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306891/restrict-route-to-controller-namespace-in-asp-net-mvc-6)

I want to allow for an API to be deprecated in the future without needing to change the url. To solve this i will put a version prefix at the start of the route. This way i can add some modifications to an endpoint without breaking any integrations with this API.

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "V1 API",
        routeTemplate: "v1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }

    );
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "V2 API",
        routeTemplate: "v2/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }

    );
```

I want to keep the same controller names and in most cases everything will be the exact same, the response and request body will be the only things that change. I have tried to add a subdirectory in the controllers folder in order to add v1 and v2 to the namespace of the controller, but i get an error about there being 2 controllers having the same name.

How can i modify the routes so that it will point to the v1 namespace for the controller instead of just searching for any class within the controller. I dont want to have to add the version to the controller name as i want to make the revision updates as seamless as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve this issue by adding the route prefix to each controller.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a URL query parameter?

`https://localhost:8000/{controller}/{action}/{id}?version=?`

You could then use control flow within the controller to determine what logic to use, based on the version.

Comment: How could I use this to route the request to the correct controller?

Comment: If you want to use separate controllers for each version, the solution @TarekAboELkheir posted would work. The only issue I find is that v2{ControllerName} looks a bit clunky.