# Two APIs running in same solution have Multiple Actions Named error

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two web API projects running in the same visual studio solutions, one calls the other.  The actions on their controllers are identical, i.e. their routes are identical.  I would have thought they belong to two completely different APIs so this should be perfectly fine although I get a `AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:` error.

Can someone shine some light on why this is happening? Is this is a quirk of running the solution in IIS express?

Comment: try to use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306891/restrict-route-to-controller-namespace-in-asp-net-core

Comment: How are you setting up routes to the actions? By convention or with attributes? If you share an example of a controller would be easier to find your problem.