# specify a route's controller namespace in ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nopcommerce-4.0

I am working in a nopCommerce 4.0 plugin, in my plugin, I want to override the `OnePageCheckout` action in `Checkout` controller. 
in the previous version Mvc, this will work with following code

```
routeBuilder.MapRoute("Plugin.Misc.TrialTracker.OnePageCheckout",
            "onepagecheckout/",
            new { controller = "Checkout", action = "OnePageCheckout" }, new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Misc.TrialTracker.Controllers" });
```

however, it doesnt work anymore in ASP.NET core. This is similar problems with the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306891/restrict-route-to-controller-namespace-in-asp-net-core) here. I can't use the solution there as I dont want to touch the default nopCommerce `Checkout` controller.

To recap, i got 2 `Checkout` controller, one is under namespace `Nop.Web.Controller`, another one is under namespace `Nop.Plugin.Misc.TrialTracker.Controllers`. and there is one default `RouteProvider` registered the route `\onepagecheckout` whith `Nop.Web.Controller.CheckoutController` controller's `OnePageCheckout` action. Without touching the default `RouteProvider` and  `Nop.Web.Controller.CheckoutController`, how can I make the route `\onepagecheckout` use my own controller action?

Thanks

Comment: You can try with priority. did you find solution to specify custom namespace ?

Answer (score -1):

Check below link 
https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/50136/overriding-controller-and-view-in-nopcommerce-40.aspx#202614

Do not create controller with same name as in Nop.web