# "AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints" error in ASP.Net Core and ExtCore.Mvc library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ExtCore.Mvc library and there's a problem when I have 2 controllers with the same name in 2 different extensions.
Here's my code:

In ExtensionA:

```
public class UseEndpointsAction : IUseEndpointsAction
{
    public int Priority => 1000;

    public void Execute(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpointRouteBuilder, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "ExtensionA",
            pattern: "ExtensionA",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index" });
    }
}
```

In ExtensionB:

```
public class UseEndpointsAction : IUseEndpointsAction
{
    public int Priority => 1000;

    public void Execute(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpointRouteBuilder, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "ExtensionB",
            pattern: "ExtensionB",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index" });
    }
}
```

There are two controllers as "ExtensionA.Controllers.DefaultController" and "ExtensionB.Controllers.DefaultController".

When client requests this URL: "http://{domain}/ExtensionA", it gets the following error:

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 
ExtensionA.Controllers.DefaultController.Index (ExtensionA)
ExtensionB.Controllers.DefaultController.Index (ExtensionB)**

I want to solve it using namespace which means to resolve each route to a specific namespace. 
I search through the web and I read all MSDN documents yet found nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rename your controllers (and change `controller = "Default"`) to `DefaultControllerA` and `DefaultControllerB` respectively.

Or you can use [areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Or try implementing some kind of `NamespaceConstraintAttribute` like was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306891/restrict-route-to-controller-namespace-in-asp-net-core).