# BeginForm messes up controller path value in .NET 6

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

after migrating my app from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET6, Html.BeginForm has started to change the slash into "%2F" in the controller path, which causes problems because then they become unreachable.

Basically, this:

```
<form action="/Admin/Report/DownloadReport" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Becomes this:

```
<form action="/Admin%2FReport/DownloadReport" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Example of code where it happens:

```
<div class="form-container">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadReport", "Admin/Report", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    @Html.Hidden("requestReportName", "PageReport");
                    <span class="epi-cmsButton">
                        <input class="epi-cmsButton-text epi-cmsButton-tools epi-cmsButton-Export" type="submit" name="btnSubmitDownloadPageReport" id="btnSubmitDownloadPageReport" value="Download Report" />
                    </span>}
</div>
```

What can be the cause of that strange behavior? I have not found any information that Html.Beginform has became obsolete in .NET6.

Edit:
My route mapping:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Admin",
                    pattern: "Admin/{controller}/{action=Index}");
```

Comment: Check what the second parameter of BeginForm expects. It looks like it should be ControllerName. So you have a controller named "Admin/Report"?

Comment: In the folder Controllers I have another folder called "Admin", in which there is a controller called "AdminController" and that's how it has worked before the migration.

Comment: @cowefe: The second parameter in the `Html.BeginForm()` is defined as `"Admin/Report"`. You told that `Admin` is name of the folder under `Controllers`.  And what is the `Report` means?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong, there is no AdminController, but there is ReportController.

Comment: @cowefe: Do you have your own custom  `IControllerFactory` interface implementation?

Comment: Also, posting your Route mapping would be helpful.

Comment: @Victor No, I don't have any implementation of that interface.

Comment: @thewallrus I have updated my question with route mapping for controllers in admin folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ASP.NET MVC

If you are working with the Built-In Controller Factory using controller name in format `Admin/Report` actually does not correct. When the built-in controller factory looking for a controller it uses controller name and looking for `Your_Controller_NameController` class in `YourApp.Controllers.*` namespaces.

It is possible to map the specific URL route by defining different namespaces using the `namespaces` parameter of the `MapRoute()` method in the ASP.NET MVC.

Try to fix the controller name in the `@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadReport", "Admin/Report", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` to `Report`. I suppose your application will find the `DownloadReport` action method without a problem.

See [RouteCollectionExtensions.MapRoute Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.routecollectionextensions.maproute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

## ASP.NET Core

I suppose after fixed the controller name in the `Html.BeginForm("DownloadReport", "Admin/Report"...)` to `"Report"` your application migration will work correct.

If you will have routing problems provide more information or see the following post: [Restrict route to controller namespace in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34306891/6630084)

Comment: I can confirm that your suggested solution has worked for me. Thanks!